# PyMySQL:- OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)")

Tags: python, mysql-workbench, pymysql

I am trying to run a scrapy spider and whenever the spider opens/scrapes/closes I am saving data to a pymysql database. When I was running on RDS it was not giving any kind of error, however when I switched to my localhost it is giving me a 'Connection refused error'.

Here's the code for my runner.py file

```
import pymysql
connection = pymysql.connect(
    host='127.0.0.1',
    port='3306',
    user='root',
    password='lifeisgood',
    db='scrapy_dev'
)
# rest of code
```

and here's the complete stacktrace of the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/technophile/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 581, in connect
    sock = socket.create_connection(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 808, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 796, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "runner.py", line 23, in <module>
    connection = pymysql.connect(
  File "/home/technophile/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/__init__.py", line 94, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/technophile/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 325, in __init__
    self.connect()
  File "/home/technophile/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 630, in connect
    raise exc
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)")
```

I've tried ways by looking at other stackoverflow answers but none of them helped so far.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Take a closer look at the configuration. It must be a configuration problem. Please check the remote code is not synchronized!

Comment: Thanks alot Arun for your prompt response, however everything seems fine in my settings.py and runner.py. which configurations apart from these are you saying?